# POWER BI - How to calculate delta values without a date variable?

Tags: powerbi

Usually delta or the change is calculated with date, but I have a different issue here in Power BI. I have a budget, which can be altered, each time the budget gets altered, we number it with a revision, so the first budget had revision = 1, and the first time we estimated a new budget, the variable "revision number" indicates = 2 for that budget. The budget consists of more than one row, usually, example, we can have material on one row and hours on second row and both can still be revision = 1, if we change material or hours, all of the budget rows will get a new revision, even though they haven't been updated for some. In my table I've filtered the budget for the last revision number, but I want to calculate the change from the second last to the last revision in budget.

I used calculate and added "lastnonblank" function in the filter context, however, I still get the same values as the last revision number.

Billingprice-1 =

CALCULATE( [Fixed price amount], LASTNONBLANK(JOBBUDGETLINE[REVISIONNUMBER],-1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variables to establish the current / prior revisions, then 'CALCULATE' to change the context to return the pror revision value. Something like:

```
Variance from Prior Revision = 
VAR RevCurrent = 
    SELECTEDVALUE ( JOBBUDGETLINE[REVISIONNUMBER] )
VAR RevPrior = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        MAX ( JOBBUDGETLINE[REVISIONNUMBER] ),
        REMOVEFILTERS ( JOBBUDGETLINE[REVISIONNUMBER] ),
        JOBBUDGETLINE[REVISIONNUMBER] < RevCurrent
    )
VAR ValueCurrent = 
    [Fixed price amount]
VAR ValuePrior = 
    CALCULATE( 
        [Fixed price amount], 
        REMOVEFILTERS ( JOBBUDGETLINE[REVISIONNUMBER] ),
        JOBBUDGETLINE[REVISIONNUMBER] = RevPrior
    )
RETURN
    IF ( 
        ISBLANK ( RevPrior ),
        BLANK(),
        ValueCurrent - ValuePrior
    )
```

Comment: Hello Olly, there is a twist. For those who only have one revision, the delta is equal to the billing price =

Comment: SELECTEDVALUE ( JOBBUDGETLINE[REVISIONNUMBER] )
VAR RevPrior = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        MAX ( JOBBUDGETLINE[REVISIONNUMBER] ),
        REMOVEFILTERS ( JOBBUDGETLINE[BELONGSTOLATESTREVISION] ),
        JOBBUDGETLINE[REVISIONNUMBER] < RevCurrent
    )
VAR ValueCurrent = 
    [Fixed price amount]
VAR ValuePrior = 
    CALCULATE( 
        [Fixed price amount], 
        REMOVEFILTERS ( JOBBUDGETLINE[BELONGSTOLATESTREVISION] ),
        JOBBUDGETLINE[REVISIONNUMBER] = RevPrior
    )
RETURN
    ValueCurrent - ValuePrior

Comment: That is due to that if you only have one revision, then the delta is equal to 0 minus current billing price ...  How can I avoid that?

Comment: See edited answer, to return `BLANK()` if there is no prior revision value.